# Number of ways to cover n×n chess board with stones of three different colors

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

I'm struggling with this problem for a few days and I'm unable to find the solution. Could someone please help me?

Question is: How many ways there is to cover a n×n chessboard with red, yellow and blue stones, so that on every square there is only one stone and no row or column is filled with stones of only one color? What if you had only red and yellow stones?
Number of stones of each color is unlimited.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: I've tried to do it using the inclusion-exclusion principle, but I'm getting lost because I have to somehow combine both rows and columns